is executor of asio always smart-ptr like?
When using asynchronous programming, the life cycle is always particularly complex. In order to control the life cycle effectively, I always try to use smart pointers to encapsulate all the objects that may be imported and exported.
In asio, executors are widely used, but getting a smart pointer to a highly compatible executor seems to be difficult. This is because they are often obtained not by direct creation, but by e.g. io_context.get_executor().
I looked at the source code for any_executor_base and realized that it seems to be some kind of smart pointer itself, so I don't need to wrap it with shared_ptr. But I'm not really sure, the documentation for asio is poor.
So can anyone tell me if asio's executor are all similar to smart pointers and manage the memory on their own.
For example, I have a io_context, and got an executor from this io_context. I have another object which need this executor as its member field.
The executor is smard-ptr-like means I can copy the executor to an object at a fraction of the cost, and I don't need to require that the io_context has to live longer than that object.

What do you mean when you say "like smart pointer"? basic_executor_type is a usual C++ class.

@3CxEZiVlQ Like a pointer mean that it is cheap to copy; Like a smart pointer means I need not care about the lifecycle of it.

An executor is a lightweight handle to the execution_context. Thus it is more like a pointer than a smart pointer. It doesn't participate in ownership. It is expected to be copied around cheaply

The lifecycle of an executor therefore is not usually relevant, one copies it or gets an associated one. The lifecycle of the execution_context that it may point to is usually relatively simple: it must be alive if an async operation is running on it...

@JeffGarrett  If I have an object A that contains an io_context and the executor obtained from this io_context is held by another object B. Is the executor held by object B still valid if object A is destructed? If object A is destructed, is the executor held by object B still valid? The validity here does not require that it can still schedule tasks, but only that it can be used without reporting errors, even if the new task is no longer executed.
